# Make a .NET Standard library COM-Visible?

Tags: .net-standard

For a full .NET project you can tick a box to make the project COM Visible in `Project Properties > Application tab > Assembly Information..`:

[image]

However, the `Assembly Information..` button doesn't exist for .NET Standard projects, instead that data is entered on the `Project Properties > Package tab`, but that tab doesn't have a checkbox for `Make Assembly COM-Visible`:

[image]

Can you still make .NET Standard libraries COM Visible by some other method, or does it not make sense to do that for some reason?

Comment: .NET standard is cross-platform while COM is platform-specific. How would you expect for the two to work together?

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek Hmm, that's a really interesting question - its' been about ten years since I last did COM, but I thought COM interop was external to the library, i.e. that it built a tlb file that defined the interface/wrapper that COM then used to talk to the library.  I.e. I thought  the library could still be cross-platform, but the wrapper would be Windows specific.  Maybe I need to write a full .NET library wrapper for my .NET Standard library... that sounds like a really bad idea!

Comment: Down voter care to comment?  I appreciate the answer may be obvious to someone who completely understands all of this, but as more people make look to move their code to .NET Standard and still want to make that code available to legacy systems, this seems like a question that will be asked and hasn't yet been asked on SO?

Comment: Microsoft sometimes skimps on the "visual" in Visual Studio.  But just not in basic dialogs like this one.  It yells "[ComVisible] is not standard!" quite loudly.  Where do you expect to go from there?  If you don't tell us why you absolutely need it anyway, and show some evidence that you know how to avoid the icebergs and torpedoes, then nobody can provide you with an alternative.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the feedback.  We have common code in shared libraries that are currently full .NET.  We would like to convert them to .Net standard so we can use those libraries across multiple platforms (EF Core, Xamarin and full .NET).  Those libraries are also used by some VBA stuff via COM, hence the hope of getting COM visibility working for those libraries. I didn't think the COM Visibility had a big impact on the compiled library code, I thought you just needed to add some attributes to the code and then that setting meant a separate tlb COM wrapper was produced when you built?

Comment: @HansPassant Continued.. so, in my ignorance, I wasn't thinking there were really any icebergs here, or no more so than the horror-show that COM can be in any other situation.

Comment: Also, what hadn't occurred to me until you made the good point about MS not always including the 'visual' part is that visual studio is not the only way to build a project.  I should look at the command line build and see if it can be achieved that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I commented on your issue at GitHub. You can definitely make .NET Standard libraries COM visible, provided the runtime you choose supports both .NET Standard and COM visibility.

Here's an example using Visual Studio 2017 and WiX:
[ComVisibleNetStandard](https://github.com/kyourek/ComVisibleNetStandard)

Answer (score 2):

@ZdeněkJelínek raises an interesting point in the comments on the question, namely that .NET Standard is supposed to be platform agnostic, whereas COM is inherently platform specific.

To test that theory I put the code from [the example of COM interop in the C# documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/example-com-class) in a full .NET solution and a .NET Standard solution.  This is the code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace project_name
{
    [Guid("EAA4976A-45C3-4BC5-BC0B-E474F4C3C83F")]
    public interface ComClass1Interface
    {
    }

    [Guid("7BD20046-DF8C-44A6-8F6B-687FAA26FA71"), 
        InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    public interface ComClass1Events 
    {
    }

    [Guid("0D53A3E8-E51A-49C7-944E-E72A2064F938"),
        ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
        ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(ComClass1Events))]
    public class ComClass1 : ComClass1Interface
    {
    }
}
```

In full .NET that compiles fine, in .NET standard it compiles fine, but triggers this warning:

> 'ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch' is obsolete: 'Support for
>   IDispatch may be unavailable in future releases.'

So at first that appears to confirm it, currently you can add the COM interfaces, but they aren't supposed to be there anymore by design.  [However, that warning shows up in the dotnet standard github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/101), and there doesn't appear to be a clear conclusion about whether these members really are obsolete.

Furthermore, `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute` shows up in [this check in for a .NET Stansard 1.6 check in for the](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/6c092eaeaec0b48c27fc14e1dc265377435c931d/netstandard/pkg/shims/netstandard/System.Runtime.Forwards.cs) `System.Runtime.Forwards.cs` class in the netstandard codebase, but I don't understand the codebase well enough to know why it's there.  Accordingly, I've [asked the question on the .NET Standard repo](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/412) and report back the answer here.