# Port C# COM dll to Linux

Tags: c#, c++, dll, .net-core

I have a .NET Framework C# dll with a COM layer that gets exposed and picked up by a customer C/C++ application. Now the customer wants to call the dll from Linux. I can port the code to .NET Core, but how do I replace the COM layer so that the customer can use the dll from their C/C++ application (without the customer having to change their code)? I can put my own C/C++ layer in as an bridge if necessary, but don't know where to start in exposing the C# side.

Edit: The COM in my original issue solved my original problem of moving between unmanaged and managed code in a Windows environment. The COM element was not going to work on Linux, so rather than trying to replace COM i should have gone back to the original issue - moving from unmanaged to managed code.
As such, there is a good article here....

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1276328/Hosting-NET-Core-Components-in-Unmanaged-C-Cpluspl

This goes some way towards solving the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a .NET Standard library COM-Visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861236/make-a-net-standard-library-com-visible)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate as COM is windows based and I'm trying to use it on Linux.

Comment: .NET Standard is cross platform.